# Redirect to www in subfolder for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My domain "example.com" is redirected to the "www.example.com". 
and the for each  it's subdomain "www.subdomain.example.com" is redirected to the "subdomain.example.com" and linked to a root subfolder "example.com/admin". So far so good.
The issue here is when I access to "/admin" for the domain itself i wanted to redirect to "www.example.com/admin" but subdomain to "subdomain.example.com/admin"  .

this is my .htaccess file in /admin:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any way I can do this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!admin).*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I try it access to "example.com/admin" it redirect me "example.com"!!

Comment: Can you comment out first rule for testing and retry this URL.